# Show number of open files on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Trying to get an idea of how many open files I'm currently using so I can tune my limits.conf file. Is there a way to get Ubuntu to spit out the current open files so I can use this to tune? I found a thread from awhile ago but the command did not work.

Comment: What command did you try, that didn't work?

Answer (score 3):

You can tune the output of `lsof` as you like. See `man lsof`.

Answer (score 1):

For a count of files open, you could do `lsof | wc -l` which would report the number of lines, which would correlate the number of files currently open.

Comment: Yea I tried lsof | wc -l yet for some reason it just hangs and I have to ^ctrl c out of it.

Comment: It will take time... you have to allow the lsof to continue until it is done.